# Tomcat is misconfigured for local IP

Tags: spring, eclipse, tomcat

I have a project on Spring with maven build. (Eclipse IDE on Windows). When I run my Spring Boot application I am getting this error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

I have tried to listen to another port (using application.properties file) but the error still persists.
I have also tried command line to kill my process using these two lines.

```
// Step 1
netstat -ano | findstr :yourPortNumber 
//Step 2
taskkill /PID typeyourPIDhere /F
```

I think my tomcat is misconfigured for the project. Weirdly, it seems to work on another project but on this one. How can that be possible? Thanks for the help in advance.

EDIT:
I am sorry but I forgot to mention that I wanted to run Tomacat on my PC's IP. It is working fine for localhost.

Here is my application.properties file:

```
spring.http.multipart.enabled=false
server.address=172.27.86.141
server.port=8080
```

Comment: show your config properties

Comment: Please check your tomcat process running like " ps -ef | grep tomcat "
and kill tomcat process like " pkill -9 pid"

Comment: I am using Windows and not Linux